# Grails 3 build with Gradle in production environment

Tags: grails, gradle

I'm using Gradle to build Grails 3.0.9 project. But it always builds in DEVELOPMENT mode. I was not managed to find anything in official documentation, tried "gradle -Pgrails.env=prod build" but still failed.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how Grails is failing (e.g. a stacktrace)?

Comment: it not failing. It just build in DEVELOPMENT environment. When I want it in PRODUCTION

Answer (score 0):

The `-P` argument that you have tried is a project property, while the `-D` argument is a system property that is passed to the JVM ([Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html)).

I'm fairly certain in this situation this command should work:

```
gradle -Dgrails.env=prod build
```

I haven't used it but it looks like the separate plugin, [Grails Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin), has another syntax that is worth trying:

```
gradle -PgrailsEnv=prod build
```

Comment: Yes, there is an old one grail-gradle plugin for Grails 2. But what is really interesting. I tried 'gradle -Dgrails.env=prod' - it works as expected for 'run' command. But 'build' still builds in development

Comment: maybe I should export it in JAVA_OPTS in setenv.sh of Tomcat where I'm actually running grails up? Will try and answer later

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not what I've experienced.

Have a look (pay attention to the last word of below log):

> ```
> $ ./gradlew clean build && java -jar build/libs/foo-0.1.war
> :clean
> :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> :compileGroovy
> :buildProperties
> :processResources
> :classes
> :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> :compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
> :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> :compileIntegrationTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> :compileIntegrationTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
> :findMainClass
> :assetCompile
> ```
>
> *some lines of noise cut off to make it shorter*
>
> ```
> :compileWebappGroovyPages UP-TO-DATE
> :compileGroovyPages
> :war
> :bootRepackage
> :assemble
> :test UP-TO-DATE
> :processIntegrationTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> :integrationTestClasses UP-TO-DATE
> :integrationTest UP-TO-DATE
> :mergeTestReports UP-TO-DATE
> :check UP-TO-DATE
> :build
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 9.873 secs
> Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: production
> ```

It's Grails **3.1.10** though. Perhaps a bug fix.